# Field of Fractions over Formal Power Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that every element in the field of fractions of $K[[X]]$ can be written as $\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_kX^k$ where $a_k\in K, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

My first attempt was to rewrite

$\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iX^i}{\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jX^j}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^N a_iX^i}{\sum_{j=0}^N b_jX^j}$

where I am not completely sure, if this is correct. I know that I can write an element of $R[[X]]$ where $R$ is a ring like this. Then I tried polynomial division and some similar things. Also I know that if $b_0$ would be not zero, I can invert the whole polynomial and arrive at the conclusion, even with $n=0$.

However, I was not able to progress from here.

Comment: $K[[X]]$ is usually the ring of power series.

Comment: I am pretty sure that general elements don't have infinitely many terms in the denominators.

Comment: @Randall $R[[X]]$ would be the ring of formal power series. Instead, here, we have the formal power series over a field $K$.

Comment: Right, but they're not "polynomials."

Comment: @Randall Corrected the title.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question: there is no requirement for $b_0$ to be a unit and, in fact, the OP has already realised they can solve the question in the case $b_0 \neq 0$ (which is equivalent to $b_0$ being a unit, since $K$ is a field).

Comment: @Christopher It is an immediate consequence of the linked dupe, since it implies that the denominator has form $\,u x^n$ for a unit $\,u\in R[[x]],\,$ see the corollary in my answer there.

Comment: I apologize for my possibly confusing voting on this question. The details of my misadventure and a kind of an explanation is given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316737/169003).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's ok. I already solved the question myself, so I might leave something for future viewers. 
HINT: Try to justify why the denominator can be written as 
$X^{-n}g(X)$ where $g(X)$ is a unit. What has to hold for "denominator polynomials" in the field of quotients of a ring?